# What's the version AWS SDK that supports TLS v1.2?

Tags: tls1.2, aws-sdk-net

We're using AWS SDK .NET for getting files from AWS S3 storage. When the application was implemented a few years ago, the AWS was only supporting TLS 1.0. Now hopefully it's supporting TLS 1.2. I'd like to know which version and where I can download the library/packages. What's the minimum requirements for the .NET Framework? We're using the AmazonS3Client to handle the underlining connection to the S3 storage account.

Answer (score 2):

Found the correct version that will be supporting the TLS 1.2. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/upgrade-aws-sdk-for-net-for-latest-tls-protocols/